# Placing app_code in subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web site with classes stored in App_Code.
If I'm running the site from server (and not locally), I get an 'missing reference error' unless the App_Code folder is in the root directory of the server.

Is there a way to get the site to work when the folder is not in the root directory (there are technical reasons that can not be solved to why I don't want it in the root)?

(most solutions i read suggest changing the directory option to 'compile', but i dot have this option).

Thanks.

Comment: Any code that is not a Page, Control must stay in App_Code folder to be JITcompiled at server. It's an ASP.NET Pattern, and you should keep It in place.

Comment: "there are technical reasons that can not be solved to why I don't want it in the root" : I'm curious to read what are these reasons.

Comment: @Fals I dont want to remove file from App_Code, I want to place the App_Code folder in sub-folder.

Comment: @cosmo0 - nothing interesting, i want to upload this site to a server that already have another site on it, since it's a private (not commercial) web site i don't want to purchase another site on the server.. (maybe technical reasons wasn't the best way to explain that)

Comment: @jta The usual solution for that is virtual applications. You'll have to see if your hosting provider has a virtual application feature. See [Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the App_folder to somewhere, It must be at the root of the Web Site, and can contain subfolders, not be nested inside one.

> Contains source code for utility classes and business objects (for example, .cs, .vb, and .jsl files) that you want to compile as part of your application. In a dynamically compiled application, ASP.NET compiles the code in the App_Code folder on the initial request to your application. Items in this folder are then recompiled when any changes are detected.

[ASP.NET Web Site Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)

If you want to remove or move things from the App_folder, you should consider to create a **New Class Library Project**, and then Add the reference to the Web Site.